# Define $T:M_{n}(\mathbf{C})\to M_{n}(\mathbf{C})$ by $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}(3 A+A^{t})$. Compute $m_{T}(x)$ and write a basis for all eigenspaces of $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

**Problem**: Define $T: M_{n \times n}(\mathbf{C}) \to M_{n \times n}(\mathbf{C})$ by $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}(3 A+A^{t})$. Compute $m_{T}(x)$ and write down a basis for all the eigenspaces of $T$.

**Attempt**:
From the relation $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}\left(3 A+A^{t}\right)$ we obtain $A^{t}=2 T(A)-3 A$. Hence,
$$
T^{2}(A)=\frac{1}{2}\left(3 T(A)+T\left(A^{t}\right)\right)=\frac{3}{2} T(A)+\frac{3}{4} A^{t}+\frac{1}{4} A
$$
Plugging the identity $A^{t}=2 T(A)-3 A$, we obtain
$$
T^{2}(A)=\frac{3}{2} T(A)+\frac{3}{4}(2 T(A)-3 A)+\frac{1}{4} A=3 T(A)-2 A
$$
This identity can be written as $\left(T^{2}-3 T+2 I\right)(A)=0$. From this we deduce that $m_{T}(x)$ divides $x^{2}-3 x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$. We deduce that $m_{T}(x)=(x-1)(x-2) $ **(** and $T-I$ and $T-2 I$ are not zero since if we assume they are zero then minimal polynomials would be $ (x-1),(x-2) $ correspondingly and we know there are two eigenvalues and each eigenvalue is a root to the minimal polynomial, so $2$ is not root to $x-1$ and $1$ is not root to $x-2$, contradiction  **)** hence, $T$ has two eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}=1$ and $\lambda_{2}=2 .$ Notice that since the minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors, then $T$ is diagonalizable.
[ I got stuck here ]

**Questions**:

1. How can I justify that I indeed found all the possible eigenvalues of $ T $?
2. How do I continue to find a basis for the eigenspaces? I thought about looking for the spans of $ \ker \{ T - I_d \} , \ker \{ T - 2I_d \} $ but the task seemed impossible.
3. Where do I use the fact that the given vector space is defined over $ \mathbb{C} $? I don't seem to be using this, maybe it is used in finding the basis which I got stuck doing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You already noted that every eigenvalue of $T$ is a zero of $m_T$ and this settles 1. For 2. have you tried to solve the equations $T(A) = A$ and $T(A) = 2 A$ for $A$? That should give you an idea how the eigenspaces look like. Regarding 3. what makes you think you have to use that you are working over $\mathbb{C}$? Everything you did should work over any field.

Comment: You're right, solving for $ T(A) = A $ implies that $ \ker (T-I_d) = Skew_n(\mathbb{C}) $ and solving  for $ T(A) = 2A $ implies that $ \ker (T-2I_d) = Sym_n(\mathbb{C}) $. Now, $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) = Skew_n( \mathbb{C}) \oplus Sym_n ( \mathbb{C} )  $ and so a basis of the eigenspaces $ V_1 = \ker (T-I_d) $ and $ V_2 = \ker (T-2I_d) $ will be the bases which span $ Skew_n(\mathbb{C}) ,Sym_n(\mathbb{C}) $ , respectively.